# problems installing condor package on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, package, condor

I tried to install the condor package on Ubuntu 12.10 but an error message appears.

Theses pictures show my problems :

[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears to me that the `condor` package is installed, just `condor_compile` isn't. On my Ubuntu 12.04 condor is also installed without condor_compile. You can check what parts are installed by typing `condor` followed by Tab+Tab in your terminal (assuming auto complete is turned on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages that ship with Ubuntu are quite old. Install using the HTCondor debian repo: http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/debian/

I run the wheezy packages on 12.04 just fine.